# what format is this "passcode" file? (found along a keystore)

Tags: ssl, openssl, pkcs#12

A Globalprotect vpn client seems to use a keystore in pfx format + a *pan_client_cert_passcode.dat* file for which I want to find out what the format is (=how to decode it).

I happen to know the passphrase (8 characters), and the passcode file seems to be binary, 16 bytes.

What format could it be?

EDIT:
To help find out: hex dump is 919e **** 77** **73 e18c fd17 d71b 1ddb and known plaintext is VD...ert (each . is a letter, each * is a hex digit)

Comment: To actually what does "format" refer to?

Comment: @csgeek clarified that, see my edit. That 8-bytes file has a password in it, it's a binary file and I'd want to know how it's encoded.

Answer (score 1):

A [Google search for pan_client_cert_passcode dat](https://www.google.com/search?q=pan_client_cert_passcode%20dat) gave me a result. There is information about this file on [paloaltonetworks.com](https://knowledgebase.paloaltonetworks.com/kCSArticleDetail?id=kA10g000000PLMa).

It seems you must have received a p12 file from paloalto. And then you create a pfx + dat file from it like this:

```
globalprotect import-certificate --location cert.p12
```

See the link. The dat file is definitely a proprietary file format used by the paloalto GlobalProtect program. It's probably encoded because they don't want to store plain text passwords on disk.

Comment: added some clarifications in title and question. Can you review my edits and adjust accordingly to get the bounty (if you find the answer)?  I know what a key store is, I even happen to know the password, but I'm curious about how it's encoded in that binary *passcode* file.

Comment: tried https://abctool.gitlab.io/encoding-detector/ on it → no result (utf-16 was a nice idea btw :-) )

Comment: Did you open it in a hex editor? Can you show us the content of the file? Maybe the .dat file does not belong to the .pfx file?

Comment: hex dump is 919e **** 77** **73 e18c fd17 d71b 1ddb and known plaintext is VD...ert (each . is a letter, each * is a hex digit)

Comment: They byte 1d tells you it's not ascii nor any unicode encoding. Ask the person you got the file from what the encoding is.

Comment: The encoding is from a VPN client (Palo Alto Networks' GlobalProtect). In this case, I know the plaintext, but I'm interested in the encoding. I doubt Palo Alto will tell me what encoding it is, reverse-engineering from a disassembly seems overkill and they didn't seem to document it either. My gut feeling is that something simple is going out, though it's not obvious for me. Could be XORed, but XORing to the plaintext from various encoding didn't seem to give a result. Any idea further?

Comment: That information that you added about the import command is definitely interesting. I'm still interested in the format, even though it's proprietary. Maybe I can find out by changing some letter :-)